# How to create an advanced primitive (value count of top n most frequent categories) with featuretools

Tags: featuretools

I want to create a primitive that would count the number of occurrences of the top n categories in a column

The following is my code:

```
import featuretools as ft
from featuretools.tests.testing_utils import make_ecommerce_entityset
from featuretools.primitives import TransformPrimitive, AggregationPrimitive
from woodwork.column_schema import ColumnSchema
from woodwork.logical_types import Categorical
class value_count(AggregationPrimitive):
    name = "value_count_top_n"
    input_types = [ColumnSchema(logical_type = Categorical)]
    return_types = ColumnSchema(semantic_tags = {"numeric"})
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def get_function(self):
        def value_counts_top_n(column):
            vc = column.value_counts().sort_values(ascending = False).iloc[:self.n]
            return list(vc)
        return value_counts_top_n


es = make_ecommerce_entityset()

feature_matrix, features = ft.dfs(
    entityset=es,
    target_dataframe_name="sessions",
    agg_primitives=[value_count(2)],
    trans_primitives=[],
)
```

This will result in the following error:

```
TypeConversionError: Error converting datatype for VALUE_COUNT_TOP_N(log.product_id, n=1) from type object to type category. Please confirm the underlying data is consistent with logical type Categorical.
```

How can I implement the desired primitive that finds a categorical column's value_counts of top n occurrences?